# Is it possible to reference any image in directory?

Tags: html, image, src

Is possible in HTML to write `<img src='some/path/*.jpg'>` or something like this so the image could be any image within the given directory?

Comment: No, you’d have to use some other language to randomly choose the image. PHP would be one way to do it.

Comment: Possibly have all the image names in a javascript array, and choose one randomly, but this would have to be coded previously, javascript doesn't have directory wildcards.